# Apple map authentication

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, mapkit

I am adding native map to my iOS application using MKMapView. I just want to be sure that Is there any kind of authentication key or application ID is require? I will be uploading this application to Apple Store.

Comment: no, you don't need any key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any API key. There is an authentication process, but it's done via code signing. If your code is signed by Apple (and has the Maps entitlement), then it is allowed to access MapKit.